# Page redirect on session empty doesn't seem to work

Tags: jsp, session

I'm tryting to redirect back to index.jsp if Session User is null and it doesn't seem to work. 
When the session is null I do get the response **"request.getSession() is null"**

JSP code.

```
<%
    if (null == session.getAttribute("User")) {
        // User is not logged in.  
        out.println("request.getSession() is null");
        String site = new String("http://localhost:8080/myproject/");
        response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        response.setHeader("Location", site);
    }
%>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
URL newUrl = new URL("yourURL");
String url = newUrl.toString();
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY); 
response.setHeader("Location", url);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error on URL class "URL cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: add the `import java.net.URL;`

Comment: That's the weird thing. Nothing. It still shows "out.println("request.getSession() is null");" when the session is null, meaning it catches the fact that it is null. But aside from that, Nothing.